# ¿Como verificar conexion a la base de datos en tiempo real con Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hola estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en la cual se conecta a una base de datos remota y necesito saber si el servidor respone o no, he investigado en internet y existe una propiedad llamada "state"

```
    PruebaEntities pruebaEntities = new PruebaEntities();

    while (true)
    {
         //Siempre imprime Closed aunque si este conectado
        Console.WriteLine(pruebaEntities.Database.Connection.State);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

El problema con esa propiedad es que no refleja los cambios en tiempo real si es que el servidor esta cerrado o no se pudo conectar por cualquier razon.

La unica forma en la que me imprime Open es si yo manualmente inicio la conexion.

```
PruebaEntities pruebaEntities = new PruebaEntities();
//Inicio la conexion manualmente, aunque si no puede conectarse, manda una excepcion
pruebaEntities.Database.Connection.Open();
    while (true)
    {
         //Ahora si imprime Open
        Console.WriteLine(pruebaEntities.Database.Connection.State);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

Pero otro problema con ello es que si el servidor cierra, esto me seguira imprimiendo Open

¿Alguien sabe como puedo obtener el estado de la conexion en tiempo real?

Comment: Dos opciones: utiliza `ping` como [en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614336/check-if-a-server-is-available); o puedes utilizar un `try-catch`, y verificar si la excepción es de tipo `TimeoutException`, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento de realizar la conexión, ya estamos hablando de tiempo real. Con los Entities Framework no se si es posible realizar estas verificaciones, yo he creado mi propio Framework que me genera todo el código de la Capa de Negocio y la Capa de acceso a datos, más todas las entidades de las tablas y solo me preocupo de la UI, ya sean web, escritorio o servicios.

Y de esta manera controlo el acceso y disponibilidad del servidor de base de datos. En cada CAPA de software.

```
/// <summary>
/// Se concecta con la base de datos.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="BaseDatosException">Si existe un error al conectarse.</exception>
public void Conectar()
{
    if (this.conexion != null && !this.conexion.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
    {
        return;
        // throw new BaseDatosException("La conexión ya se encuentra abierta.");
    }
    try
    {
        if (this.conexion == null)
        {
            this.conexion = factory.CreateConnection();

            this.conexion.ConnectionString = cadenaConexion;
        }
        this.conexion.Open();
    }
    catch (DataException ex)
    {
        throw new BaseDatosException("Error al conectarse a la base de datos.", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new BaseDatosException("Error al conectarse a la base de datos.", ex);
    }
}
```

Luego si existe un error en la conexion desde la capa de negocio la capturo con la excepcion que definido **BaseDatosException**

Así:

```
/// <summary>
/// Representa un error genérico producido en las reglas de negocio.
/// De esta clase deben heredar las clases que representen errores 
/// específicos de reglas de negocio.
/// </summary>
public class ReglasNegocioException : ApplicationException
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Construye una instancia con un mensaje de error, 
    /// invocando al constructor de la clase base.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mensaje">El mensaje de error.</param>
    /// <param name="original">El error original.</param>
    public ReglasNegocioException(string mensaje, Exception original)
        : base(mensaje, original)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Construye una instancia con un mensaje de error, 
    /// invocando al constructor de la clase base.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mensaje">El mensaje de error.</param>
    public ReglasNegocioException(string mensaje)
        : base(mensaje)
    {
    }

}
```

Ejemplo de un metodo que trae los datos y que además controla la conexión con el servidos de datos, fijate en los try y catch:

```
/// <summary>
/// Obtiene una lista de un elemento
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Es el numero de factura a obtener</param>
/// <returns>Retorna una lista de tipo Facturas de un elemento</returns>
public List<DBClass.Facturas> Get(float id)
{
    var oObject = new List<DBClass.Facturas>();
    DB.Conectar();

    try
    {
        DB.CrearComando("FacturasSelProc @id");
        DB.AsignarParametroDouble("@id", id);

        DbDataReader dr = DB.EjecutarConsulta();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // Convertimos el DataRead a DataTable para obtener el RowsAffects
        dt.TableName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
        dt.Load(dr);
        this.count = dt.Rows.Count;

        // Si hay registros los pasamos al XML tipo esquema
        //
        if (this.count > 0)
        {
            System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            dt.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            this.toxml = writer.ToString();
        }

        // Convertimos el DataTable a DataReader
        DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(dt);

        if (reader == null)
        {
            this.count = 0;
            return null;
        }
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                DBClass.Facturas e = new DBClass.Facturas()
                {
                    Foliofactura       = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Foliofactura"))       ? 0 : (float)reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("Foliofactura")),
                    Idcliente          = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Idcliente"))          ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Idcliente")),
                    Periodo            = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("periodo"))            ? "" : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("periodo")),
                    Fecha              = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Fecha"))              ? Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900") : reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Fecha")),
                    Vendedor           = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Vendedor"))           ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Vendedor")),
                    Estadofactura      = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Estadofactura"))      ? "" : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Estadofactura")),
                    Neto               = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Neto"))               ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Neto"))),
                    Total_iva          = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Total_iva"))          ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Total_iva"))),
                    Totalfactura       = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("TotalFactura"))       ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("TotalFactura"))),
                    Total_iaba1        = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Total_iaba1"))        ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Total_iaba1"))),
                    Total_iaba2        = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Total_iaba2"))        ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Total_iaba2"))),
                    Glosa              = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("glosa"))              ? "" : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("glosa")),
                    SubTotal           = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("SubTotal"))           ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("SubTotal"))),
                    TasaImpIva         = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("TasaImpIva"))         ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("TasaImpIva"))),
                    Vencimiento        = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Vencimiento"))        ? Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900") : reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Vencimiento")),
                    Observacion        = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Observacion"))        ? "" : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Observacion")),
                    CondicionPago      = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("CondicionPago"))      ? 0 : (int)reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("CondicionPago")),
                    OrdenCompra        = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("OrdenCompra"))        ? 0 : (int)reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("OrdenCompra")),
                    GuiaDespacho       = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("GuiaDespacho"))       ? 0 : (int)reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("GuiaDespacho")),
                    Descuento          = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Descuento"))          ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Descuento"))),
                    NroReferenciaVenta = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("NroReferenciaVenta")) ? 0 : (Double) reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("NroReferenciaVenta")),
                    DocReferenciaVenta = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("DocReferenciaVenta")) ? "" : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DocReferenciaVenta")),
                    TipoFactura        = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("TipoFactura"))        ? "" : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("TipoFactura")),
                };
                oObject.Add(e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ReglasNegocioException(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        if (oObject.Count == 1)
        {
            this.Foliofactura = oObject[0].Foliofactura;
            this.Idcliente = oObject[0].Idcliente;
            this.Fecha = oObject[0].Fecha;
            this.Periodo = oObject[0].Periodo;
            this.Vendedor = oObject[0].Vendedor;
            this.Estadofactura = oObject[0].Estadofactura;
            this.Neto = oObject[0].Neto;
            this.Total_iva = oObject[0].Total_iva;
            this.Totalfactura = oObject[0].Totalfactura;
            this.Glosa = oObject[0].Glosa;
            this.SubTotal = oObject[0].SubTotal;
            this.TasaImpIva = oObject[0].TasaImpIva;
            this.Total_iaba1 = oObject[0].Total_iaba1;
            this.Total_iaba2 = oObject[0].Total_iaba2;
            this.Vencimiento = oObject[0].Vencimiento;
            this.Observacion = oObject[0].Observacion;
            this.CondicionPago = oObject[0].CondicionPago;
            this.OrdenCompra = oObject[0].OrdenCompra;
            this.GuiaDespacho = oObject[0].GuiaDespacho;
            this.Descuento = oObject[0].Descuento;
            this.NroReferenciaVenta = oObject[0].NroReferenciaVenta;
            this.DocReferenciaVenta = oObject[0].DocReferenciaVenta;
            this.TipoFactura = oObject[0].TipoFactura;

        }
        reader.Close();
        return oObject;
    }
    catch (BaseDatosException ex)
    {
        throw new ReglasNegocioException(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        DB.Desconectar();
    }
}
```

Y Finalmente desde la interfaz de usuario hago lo siguiente para capturar problemas en la conexión desde la interfaz de usuario (fijate en los cacht):

```
    // Ingreso de la factura
    //
    clsFacturas oFactura = new clsFacturas();
    int n;
    if ( Int32.TryParse(txtFolio.Text, out n) )
        oFactura.Foliofactura = n;

    Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtSubTotal.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);

    oFactura.SubTotal      = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtSubTotal.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);
    oFactura.TasaImpIva    = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtIVA.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);
    oFactura.Neto          = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtNeto.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);
    oFactura.Totalfactura  = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtTotal.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency); 
    oFactura.Descuento     = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtDescuento.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency); 
    oFactura.Estadofactura = "FE";
    oFactura.Fecha         = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFecha.Text);
    oFactura.Glosa         = txtGlosa.Text;
    oFactura.Vencimiento   = dtpVencimiento.Value;
    oFactura.Observacion   = txtObservacion.Text;
    oFactura.CondicionPago = cmbCondicion.SelectedValue == null ? 0: Convert.ToInt32( cmbCondicion.SelectedValue );

    oFactura.Total_iaba1   = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtIaba1.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);
    oFactura.Total_iaba2   = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtIaba2.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency); 

    oFactura.NroReferenciaVenta = NroReferenciaVenta.Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(NroReferenciaVenta.Text);
    oFactura.DocReferenciaVenta = cmbReferencia.SelectedValue == null ? "" : cmbReferencia.SelectedValue.ToString();

 // oFactura.OrdenCompra   = txtDocRefVenta.Text.Length == 0 ? 0: Convert.ToInt32( txtDocRefVenta.Text );
 // oFactura.GuiaDespacho  = txtGuia.Text.Length == 0 ? 0: Convert.ToInt32( txtGuia.Text );
    
    n = 0;
    if ( Int32.TryParse(txtRut.Text, out n) )
        oFactura.Idcliente = n;

    oFactura.Total_iva = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtMontoIva.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);
    string sMes = "0" + dtpFecha.Value.Month.ToString();

    oFactura.Periodo    = dtpFecha.Value.Year.ToString() + sMes.Substring((sMes.Length - 2), 2);
    oFactura.SubTotal   = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtSubTotal.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);
    oFactura.TasaImpIva = Single.Parse(GlobalVar.FormatNumero(txtIVA.Text).ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency);
    oFactura.Vendedor   = Convert.ToInt32(lblVendedor.Text);
    //
    // Detalle de facturas
    //
    clsDetalleFacturas[] oDetfacturas = new clsDetalleFacturas[c1FlexGrid2.Rows.Count - 2];
    List<clsDetalleFacturas> oDetalles = new List<clsDetalleFacturas>();

    try
    {
        int nItem = 1;

        foreach (C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row row in c1FlexGrid2.Rows)
        {
            var prd = row["colProducto"];
            if (row.IsNew || prd == null)
                break;

            if (row.Index > 0)
            {
                var odet = new clsDetalleFacturas()
                {
                    Item = nItem++,
                    Idproducto = row["colProducto"].ToString(),
                    Descripcion = row["colDescripcion"].ToString(),
                    Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(row["colCantidad"]),
                    Descuento = Convert.ToSingle(row["colDescuento"]),
                    Valorunitario = Convert.ToSingle(row["colPrecio"]),
                    Totalitem = Convert.ToSingle(row["colTotalItem"]),
                    Iaba = Convert.ToSingle(row["colTipoIaba"]),
                    Totaliaba = Convert.ToSingle(row["colTotalIaba"]),
                    MontoDescuento = Convert.ToSingle(row["colMontoDes"]),
                };
                //
                //  
                //
                oDetalles.Add(odet);
            }
        }
        //
        //
        if (!oFactura.GrabarFactura(oFactura, oDetalles.ToArray()))
        {
            clsLogs logs = new clsLogs();
            logs.Save("REGVTA", "INFAC", GlobalVar.Usuario, String.Format("Error, no se pudo registrar la factura de venta (Tipo Documento: {0}, Folio: {1})", oFactura.TipoDTE, oFactura.Foliofactura));
        }

        LeerDatosFactura();
        oFactura.ExportInvoiceToBNC(oFactura.Foliofactura);

        MessageBox.Show("Los datos se han guardado correctamente!, \r Se a generado la factura folio: " + oFactura.Foliofactura.ToString(), "Diálogo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        LimpiaForm();
    }
    catch (ReglasNegocioException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
}
```

Con eso controlo todo el tiempo la condición de la conexión al servidor de base de datos, me funciona perfectamente con aplicaiones web, de escritorio, servicio windows, y worker services.

La unico importante es, que todo este trabajo la hace la aplicación que  construi, yo solo me precupo de la interfaz ya que me genera hasta los procedimientos almacenados.

[image: Así se ve]

Esto genera:

Las entidades
Código de la capa de negocio
Y Procedimientos Almacenados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los SP
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las Clases de la capa de negocio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Las entidades
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usar tu propio Framework te da mas liberta de manipular todo!!!
Piensa en eso he inspirate en tu propia forma de trabajo para crear tu metologia propia, es lo mas facil tendras el control total.

Comment: Apreciable esfuerzo, y seguramente muchísima experiencia detrás, sin embargo, cómo responde esto a la pregunta de OP?

Comment: Si no es posible que puedas realizar tu propio codificación, aquí un articulo de como realizar control de errores en Entity Fremework, suerte.
https://blog.elmah.io/common-exceptions-and-fixes-in-entity-framework-and-sql-server/

Comment: Lo que indica José Donoso, es lo mejor que puedes realizar. Ya que tienes el control de todo. De lo contrario tienes que depender de código de terceros (EntityFramework) que además es gigante. En el fondo lo que indica es algo simple y con un poco trabajo, con el tiempo que inviertes en desarrollar tu propio Framework, ganas en la rapidez de las conexiones, y al traer grandes cantidades de datos de das cuenta que usar Entity Framework no es una buena opción cuando desarrollas aplicaciones empresariales vs lo expuesto por él.